# can't find my url service on jax-rs and wildfly

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly

I have this service

`@ApplicationPath("/services") public class MyRestEasyApplication extends Application {`
Packeged package bitsexcel.ws.resteasy.services; My project is named RsJavaWeb and run in this url http://localhost:8080/RsJavaWeb/   on Wilfly Server
I have not web.xml descriptor with nothing except `<welcome-file-list>`
I can't find my service in any url

[image: project structure]

I tried with:
http://localhost:8080/RsJavaWeb/services/person/1
http://localhost:8080/RsJavaWeb/ ?
And ever more but I can't find the service

Answer (score 0):

Find the context root of your application (you can see it from WildFly UI console).
Then you should send requests at `http://localhost:8080/{context-root}/services/...`

Comment: I am going to try, tnx